# Parse.com JQuery check if array value is in parse field

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I'm working on a search box for my site and want to build if from scratch (I know I probably shouldn't but it's a learning exercise as much as anything).

I am receiving a string from a text box and using the Jquery autocomplete function to display any results from Parse.

So far this works OK but when I type in a string that includes all the words in my database, but not in the correct order, I get no results.

e.g. if I search for "New article" it shows the article, whereas if I search for "article New" it doesn't.

I am retrieving the data with:

```
  ...

  var searchString = document.getElementById("tags").value; // Get the search string
  var str = searchString.split(" "); // Split it up into an array

  var Articles = Parse.Object.extend("Articles");
  var query = new Parse.Query(Articles);

  query.containedIn("title", str); // This part doesn't work.
  // query.contains("title", searchString); // I was using this and it works OK.

  query.find({ 

  ...
```

EDIT:

Using the method suggested by bond below my cloud code is:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('searchArticles', function(request, response) {
console.log("About to request search terms"); // This never appears in cloud code logs

var input = request.params.searchTerms;
input = _.uniq(input);
input = _.filter(list, function(w) { return w.match(/^\w+$/); });

var searchQuery = new Parse.Query("Articles");
searchQuery.containedIn("titleArray", input);
  searchQuery.find().then(function(articles) {
    console.log("Success");
  }, function(err) {
    console.log("Failure");
  });
});
```

and the function i'm using to call this is:

```
$("#searchBox").keyup(function() {

var availableArticles = [];
var searchString = document.getElementById("tags").value;
var str = searchString.split(" ");

Parse.Cloud.run('searchArticles', {"searchTerms":str}, {
success: function(articles) {
  alert("Successful");
},
error: function(error) {
  alert("Unsuccessful");
}
});
```

Note that none of the console.log's are ever written, and the alerts in the `Parse.Cloud.run` function never appear. The cloud code is running as it is displayed in Parse cloud code logs.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: To make it more clear, please use quotations around strings you are reffering to, e.g. in the phrase: "New article" it shows "this article", whearas if I search for "article New" it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

For search functions you may use a separate array column say keyWords. Where you save the keywords in title column in `beforeSave` function of Articles class. Then you may call separate search function to search while you type to search. Something like this:

```
    Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Articles", function(request, response) {
    // set/update Articles keywords
}

Parse.Cloud.define("searchArticles", function(request, response) {
    var input = request.params.query; //
    // optimizing input
    input = _.uniq(input);
    input = _.filter(list, function(w) { return w.match(/^\w+$/); });

    var searchQuery = new Parse.Query("AddressInfo");
    searchQuery.containsAll("keyWords", input);
    searchQuery.find().then(function(articles) {
        // return success response
    }, function(err) {
        // handle error
    });
}
```

You may call `searchArticles` from client. Running queries like `containedIn` in Cloud than on client would be faster to give your search results.

Comment: Hi @bond, I don't want to use containsAll, I would like any string from the array of search terms to be contained in the title of the article. Can I do that? So if it has "article" but not "New" then it should still show the article titled "New article".

Comment: Yes you may pass "article" to `searchArticles` and use `containedIn` instead of `containsAll`. I just gave the sample solution, you may modify it accordingly.

Comment: Great - working through this now. I'm trying to figure out how I pass  searchKw but am guessing this is on the Parse docs so will work through that and come back to you.. Much appreciated @bond.

Comment: I will thanks... can you confirm in your code above, should `searchKw` be `input` if I am passing in an array to this cloud function?

Comment: I think I'm having issues passing the data in. Would I be correct in thinking that I can receive the string (which is working) then create an array using `var searchTerms = searchQuery.split(" ")` and then use `Parse.Cloud.run('searchArticles', str, {` to call the cloud function? Note: When the user saves a new article it creates an array of terms and saves them to "titleArray" in the Parse database.

Comment: You may do either side. Did you notice the same in my code: `input = _.filter(list, function(w) { return w.match(/^\w+$/); });`

Comment: That was a bit above me :) I'm still not clear on this. It seems that my cloud code is running (from the Logs on cloud code), but if I `console.log` anything within the cloud function it never gets written here so I suspect its failing somewhere. I'll update my question with current state of code and If you don't mind having a look that would be hugely appreciated!